# data type to save RNcryptor output in sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsdata, rncryptor

I am using RNCryptor to encrypt my data. I want to save that encrypted data and store in sqlite and the retrieve it back and send  to decrypt function.

I have tried saving encrypted output as string in sqlite but it does not work.

Can someone suggest what data type can i use?

will using blob be a better option?
thanks

Comment: "I have tried saving encrypted output as string in sqlite but it does not work." What do you mean by that? The String was nil/empty? What's wrong with saving a String into SQLite?

Comment: The RNCCryptor function gave output as NSData and once I was unable to store it as String. However I sed it as a blob and it worked fine. Thanks @Larme